# A Simple Bluetooth Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, bluetooth, sh

Hello I need help with this Bluetooth shell script, as you can see the Bluetooth script is searching for a Bluetooth device with a specific MAC address and connects to it automatically, but my device sometimes it turns off and on again! Due to an issue, I need the script to be very aware when I lost a Bluetooth connection! And he automatically search and connects to it fast again.

```
#!/bin/bash
MAC="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
powered() {
    echo "show" | bluetoothctl | grep "Powered" | cut -d " " -f 2
}

connected() {
    echo "info ${MAC}" | bluetoothctl | grep "Connected" | cut -d " " -f 2
}

while true
do
    sleep 1
    if [ $(powered) = yes ] && [ $(connected) = no ]; then
        echo "connect ${MAC}" | bluetoothctl
        sleep 5
    fi
done
```

Comment: And...  What is wrong with this code?  What does it do that is different from what you want?

Comment: It doesn't connect to the Bluetooth device automatically after the device turns off and on again! the script just stopped

Comment: I've run your script. I've tested by turning off the power for both the Bluetooth dongle on my Raspberry Pi and the remote device. The shell script continues to run and connect once the devices are powered on again. Without an error message or more detail it will be difficult to help.

Comment: Alright thanks, I would like to add some additional code to that script, I want it to whatever he connects to the device, he automatically plays music mp3 inside the directory (or a specific music) and when the device turns off, music also stops (or exit) then when the device turns on back again he connects to it (like usual) then resume music (or play it again).